# clearing child controls from wrappanel does not clear memory and references

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, user-controls, wrappanel

### Issue

I have a wrappanel which is beeing used to apply tags to an image.
Tags can be added and removed:
[image]

The problem is the following: Upon removing an element, the memory is not released and also never garbage collected.

this is how I add the Control:

```
foreach (MetadataAttribute attribute in metadata.attributes)
{
    this.Attributes_StackPanel.Children.Add(new Attribute(attribute));
}
```

this is how i removed the elements initially:

```
this.Attributes_StackPanel.Children.Clear();
```

### What I tried

I found multiple resources and questions about the topic, but none of them seemed to work for me:

- name properties have to be set to null before clearing
- grids and stackpanels have to be cleared
- all references sould be cleared
- the element itself should be cleared
- name property of the parent should be cleared

I wandered through posts until I ended with an abomination like this:

parent:

```
/// <summary>
/// clears the attribute panel to prepare for new metadata to be loaded
/// </summary>
private void ClearAttributesPanel()
{
    for(int i = this.Attributes_StackPanel.Children.Count-1; i > 0; i--)
    {

        Attribute attr = (Attribute)this.Attributes_StackPanel.Children[i];
        attr.Delete();
        attr = null;
    }
}
```

xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Minter_UI.Attribute"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Minter_UI"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800" Padding="0.1cm, 0.1cm, 0, 0">
    <Grid x:Name="Main_Grid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="1cm"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5cm"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel x:Name="Stack_Panel"  Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="0">
            <ComboBox x:Name="TraitType_ComboBox" IsEditable="True" Text="TraitType" SelectionChanged="TraitType_ComboBox_SelectionChanged"></ComboBox>
            <ComboBox x:Name="Value_ComboBox" IsEditable="True" Text="Value"></ComboBox>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Label Content="MinValue" Grid.Column="0"></Label>
                <Label Content="MaxValue" Grid.Column="1"></Label>
                <TextBox x:Name="MinValue_TextBox" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"></TextBox>
                <TextBox x:Name="MaxValue_TextBox" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"></TextBox>
            </Grid>
            
        </StackPanel>
        
        <Button x:Name="Delete_Button" Content="X" Background="LightCoral" Grid.Column="1" Click="Delete_Button_Click"></Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Attribute delete:

```
public void Delete()
{
    // unregister events
    this.TraitType_ComboBox.SelectionChanged -= this.TraitType_ComboBox_SelectionChanged;
    this.Delete_Button.Click -= this.Delete_Button_Click;
    // main grid
    this.Main_Grid.Children.Clear();
    this.Main_Grid = null;
    // stack panel
    this.Stack_Panel.Children.Clear();
    this.Stack_Panel = null;
    // textboxes
    this.MinValue_TextBox.Text = null;
    this.MinValue_TextBox = null;
    this.MaxValue_TextBox.Text= null;
    this.MaxValue_TextBox = null;
    //comboboxes
    this.TraitType_ComboBox.ItemsSource= null;
    this.TraitType_ComboBox.SelectedItem= null;
    this.TraitType_ComboBox.Text= null;
    this.TraitType_ComboBox = null;
    this.Value_ComboBox.ItemsSource = null;
    this.Value_ComboBox.SelectedItem = null;
    this.Value_ComboBox.Text = null;
    this.Value_ComboBox = null;
    // delete button
    this.Delete_Button.Content = null;
    this.Delete_Button = null;
    // clear all x:name properties
    this.UnregisterName("Stack_Panel");
    this.UnregisterName("MinValue_TextBox");
    this.UnregisterName("MaxValue_TextBox");
    this.UnregisterName("TraitType_ComboBox");
    this.UnregisterName("Value_ComboBox");
    this.UnregisterName("Main_Grid");
    this.UnregisterName("Delete_Button");
    // remove self from parent
    ((Panel)this.Parent).Children.Remove(this);
}
```

Still, this doesnt work. I can find thousands of references to the comboboxes and textpanels  as well as hashtables in heap after enough reloads. After a while, the garbage collector goes crazy but never actually clears any elements.

Comment: Are there any event handlers involved which should be removed before deleting?

Comment: How does the "X" button work? Is there an event handler in the parent control/vm to the children controls/vms?

Comment: you mean something like Delete_Button.Click? Those wold be dhe only event handlers which I know of

Comment: @SvenBardos button has a Click event which calls this.Delete()

Comment: Did you Try to dispose object? Class object are not removed if there are still links attached to the object.  Class objects use ByRef and an object can have more than one link.  The garbage disposal does not dispose an object if links still exist to prevent exceptions.  Also Net does not copy objects, just adds links.  So you may think you made a copy of an object, but you just added an new link to object.  Then when you try to delete object does not get disposed because a link still exists.

Comment: wpf user controls cannot be disposed. If this is incorrect, please give an example of how to dispose the user control.

Answer (score 0):

I dont kow if this is the way to do it but it works:

1. add a function to repopulate the properties to the child control xaml.cs:

```
public void SetAttribute(MetadataAttribute attribute)
{
    // you need to extend the function, its just an example
    this.TraitType_ComboBox.Text = attribute.trait_type.ToString();
    this.Value_ComboBox.Text = attribute.@value.ToString();
    this.MinValue_TextBox.Text = attribute.min_value.ToString();
    this.MaxValue_TextBox.Text = attribute.max_value.ToString();
}
```

2. to the parent which holds the collection, add a queue and adjust the remove function to add the elements to the queue instead of destroying them:

```
Queue<Attribute> AttributeReuseElements = new Queue<Attribute>();
private void ClearAttributesPanel()
{
    for(int i = this.Attributes_StackPanel.Children.Count-1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        AttributeReuseElements.Enqueue((Attribute)this.Attributes_StackPanel.Children[i]);
        this.Attributes_StackPanel.Children.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

3. upon loading of the elements, recycle the previously removed elements from the queue:

```
foreach (MetadataAttribute attribute in CollectionInformation.Information.LikelyAttributes)
{
    if (AttributeReuseElements.Count > 0)
    {
        Attribute attr = AttributeReuseElements.Dequeue();
        attr.SetAttribute(attribute);
        this.Attributes_StackPanel.Children.Add(attr);
    }
    else
    {
        this.Attributes_StackPanel.Children.Add(new Attribute(attribute));
    }
}
```

This will not neglect the memory leak from manually pressing the delete button of the control but this will likely be neglible.
Whenever the information is reloaded however, elements get recycled instead of destroyed and created freshly.

This might have some implications if you do not make sure all fields and values are properly cleared. For example you might find values from the previus property.